# ui router race condition?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have noticed a possible race condition that can occur when I quickly navigate between states.

Let's say that I navigate to state A. The directives associated with the state are compiled. This may take a while if some nested directives use templateURls that are compiled asynchronously.

While this is going on, I transition to a new state B. The ui-view of the original state is destroyed. However some of the nested inner directives may still be compiling!

The nested compilation can throw an exception if there are dependencies it is looking for that have already been destroyed.

It feels like asynchronous compilation doesn't play well with UI-router? How can I avoid these types of issues?

Answer (score 0):

Using Angularjs resolver function first all your directives and files and also maintain a good architecture so that your application transition is enhanced.

resolve all dependencies on which your your directive dependent upon such as http requests and service handling or I/O operation

you may use this following link for resolvers
https://toddmotto.com/resolve-promises-in-angular-routes/